# Unable to create image out of a base 64 encoded string posted from browser

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I have to send an img from client side (JavaScript) to server side Jaxrs implementation.

Client side:

```
function sendRequest()
{
  var url = 'http://localhost:8080/MobilePOC/restService/uploadImage';
  $("body").append('<canvas id="theCanvas" style="display:none" width="300px"  
           height="300px"></canvas>');
  var canvas = document.getElementById('theCanvas');  
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.src = "myjpg.jpeg";  
  context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 300, 300);
  $.post(url, {'image':canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), 'url':'caption'},  
    function(file){               
        //Callback code
        alert("done");
    });
}
```

And on server side in JAXRS I am using:

Its working but the issue is when I convert the base64 string back to image its not working. It is creating blank image instead of original image.

```
    @POST
    @Path("/uploadImage")
    @Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
    public Response upload(String image) {  
        System.out.println("In upload:"+image);

        Base64 decoder = new Base64();
        try {       
           byte[] imgBytes = decoder.decode(image);  
           FileOutputStream osf;
           osf = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/yourImage.jpg"));
           osf.write(imgBytes);  
           osf.flush();  
           osf.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
        } 
            // store input somewhere
            return Response.ok().build();   
    }
```

I tried replacing few characters in the encoded string but with no success.

Comment: Whats the error/eception when/if you try to interpret it as an image? (Are you using java 1.7.04 (on OsX?)?).

Comment: Iam not getting any error when i write it to file,I am getting blank image and iam using java 1.6

Comment: "getting a blank image" doesn't tell me/us much. How does the file look compared to what you sent (send smaller amounts of bytes too see) Sometimes there is a problem with B64 where one of decode/encode uses padding and the other doesn't. Try sending 1 byte then 3 bytes. If 3 works and not 1 you probably have a padding problem.

Answer (score 0):

The base64 'string' should actually be an array of strings, or at least should have multiple lines of maximum length 76 bytes each, delimited by newlines.
Decode each of these lines or strings, and send it to the OutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Have look at this [code ranch link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/482256/java/java/Converting-Base-encoded-String-Image)

May be some issue with encoding in jpeg in the client side and decoding to jpg in the server side.

Comment: yes,i looked at that link but the code that hanuman has written has some compilation errors so left it .I will try solve it and again look into that code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify `URL_SAFE` option to your `Base64.decode` function.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Base64 string at client side and at server side.If it is not same then find out difference.

Check this link to find out the solution 
[Base64 String discarding some data problem link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594596/invalid-jpeg-file-structure-missing-sos-marker/18915210#18915210)