# Invalid JPEG file structure: missing SOS marker

Tags: java

Firstly,I captured image using Phonegap 3.0 which gives me BASE64 encoded String and then
I have converted BASE64 string into MultipartFile object using [How to convert byte array to MultipartFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381928/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-multipartfile) link.

```
scalePhoto(ORIGINAL_LONG_EDGE,(new BASE64DecodedMultipartFile(Base64.decodeBase64(base64EncodedString).getBytes())
```

Check link for above class.

I am getting

> Invalid JPEG file structure: missing SOS marker.

How can i resolve that?

Comment: What is the Base64 data? Why do you think a multipart file can be converted to a JPEG?

Comment: It is image data converted into BASE64 using camera plugin of Phonegap 3.0 and in my project while storing into server we are using MultipartFile

Answer (score 1):

Obviously something gets lost during the conversion or the inverse conversion.

1. check the if your JPEG handling code can handle the JPEG file produced by Photoshop, in other words, get rid of the Base64 encoding/decoding and the multi-part file stuff. Isolate the JPEG and feed the "real" data.
2. Binary compare the original JPEG and the binary file what you get at the end of the base64decode and multi-part join operations. Probably the wont' be the same.
3. Isolate only the Base64 encoding/decoding and test that with the JPEG file. (binary compare the the JPEG files again).
4. Isolate only the multi-part break up and join to see if that loose any info. (binary compare the the JPEG files again).

Comment: But if you see the link which i provided has method getInputStream() and it is giving exactly the same file which is send or uploaded